# how to place figures on the same page as the appendix heading

Tags: appendix

I'm trying to create an appendix where each appendix A, B, C, etc contains one or two figures. The problem is that the following code:

```
\appendix

\section{Pass 1}
\label{int1}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, height=0.8\textheight]{1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, height=0.8\textheight]{11}
\end{figure}

\section{Pass 2}
\label{int2}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, height=0.8\textheight]{2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, height=0.8\textheight]{22}
\end{figure}
```

places the heading (title?) of the appendix on its own page and the figure is placed on a separate page. I want them both to be placed on the same page. When I try putting text instead of figures beneath the \section{} command in the \appendix environment, there's no problem. The problem arise with the figures.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: This may be document class dependent.  \let\part=\chapter\appendix might fix it.